# I keep getting this error from angular-bootstrap-lightbox " Cannot read property 'openModal' of undefined" assuming all dependencies are loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

this is how I implemented it

```
var ngModule = angular.module('appunit',['ui.bootstrap','bootstrapLightbox']);
ngModule.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', 'CallApi', function ($scope, CallApi, Lightbox)
{

 $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) 
  {
   Lightbox.openModal($scope.listImages ,index);
 };

}]);
```

by calling the openLightboxModal(index) in the HTML dom lead to this error

```
Cannot read property 'openModal' of undefined"
```

I tried something like this
     ['$scope', 'CallApi','Lightbox',  function ($scope, CallApi, Lightbox)
 but still no luck.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have code like that:

```
var ngModule = angular.module('appunit',['ui.bootstrap','bootstrapLightbox']);
ngModule.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', 'CallApi', 'Lightbox', function ($scope, CallApi, Lightbox)
{

 $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) 
  {
   Lightbox.openModal($scope.listImages ,index);
 };

}]);
```

then the assumption must be wrong as it's clearly undefined, maybe if you can post the way you include modules it would draw a bit of light on it

#### ---edit---

ater exchaning comments with OP I got to Lightbox source, it appears that it requires version v.0.14.x of `ui-bootstrap` as up from this version Lightbox can use the modal

Comment: this is how I add all Js files
  protected $_jsScripts =[
        "js/jquery-1.11.3.js",
        "js/angular.js", 
        "js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
        "js/lightbox.js",
        "js/app.js",    
    ];

Comment: `ngModule.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', 'CallApi', 'Lightbox', function ($scope, CallApi, Lightbox)` i mean this line

Comment: I have gone throgh the Lightbox-docs over and over agian. I`m following the right steps but yet the openModal property of lightbox is still not seen

Comment: I had the 'Lightbox' before the function removed.

Comment: but that results to this error  Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- Lightbox <- Lightbox

Comment: Lightbox HAS TO BE INCLUDED that way, and the error indicates that it's missing something, I'd suggest checking if correct bootstrap is loaded

Comment: but then comes the next question. What is it missing ?

Comment: are you using correct bootstrap version? from what I see it needs v0.14

Comment: Dude you have been a great help man. I was using v0.13 and never thought it could matter. Thanks A LOT mate

Comment: @maurycy is there anyway we can use that gallery with latest bootstrap?